# Get SelectedItem value from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, entity-framework-4

I have a **DataGrid** in my **WPF** application as below.

```
<DataGrid Name="stDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" CanUserResize="False" Width="SizeToHeader">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button" Click="btnEdit_Click">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="images/edit.png"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Age}" Header="Age" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Sex}" Header="Sex" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Binding data into DataGrid like this.

```
using (var context = new CLASS_DBEntities())
{
var query = from s in context.STUDENT
            orderby s.STUDENT_NAME
            select new {s.STUDENT_ID, Name = s.STUDENT_NAME, Age = s.STUDENT_AGE, 
                        Sex = s.STUDENT_SEX};

stDataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

When user click Button in DataGrid, I need to get `STUDENT_ID` value. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set an attached property of the same type as `student_id` on your button and bind it relativly to the `datacontext.student_id` of the **DataGridRow** control which should be the parent to all yours cells in a row.

Once you enter `btnEdit_Click` method just read out the value from your attached property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain this more using example. i'm new to wpf. so i can't understand this clearly.

Comment: Attached properties is a wpf concept allowing a control eg button to be extended. Thats how you can tell your button you have a property called student_id. And when you click on your button you simply read out the value from the attached property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Finally found answer by myself.

in `btnEdit_Click` method,

```
dynamic customerRow = stDataGrid.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(customerRow.STUDENT_ID+"");
```